# Issue related to angular overlay cdk global positioning strategy and dropping element anywhere in grey area

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cdk

I am following a tutorial and have implemented drag and drop, however I am facing 2 issues

1. On using  new GlobalPositionStrategy(document); in **draggable-helper.directive.ts** file under draggable folder , shows an error stating Expected 0 arguments but got 1 , due to which I am not able to get the desired outcome as in this link 
   https://stackblitz.com/edit/draggable-part-6-4lwvqa?file=app/app.component.html
2. I can drag and drop the boxes in grey area but the issue is , the boxes which I drag and drop goes and sits in the same top,left position in grey area every time I drag and drop.

Where as the expectation the  box can be dragged and dropped anywhere within the grey area(once I drag and drop ,after that I am able to move the box anywhere , whereas the expectation the  box can be dragged and dropped anywhere within the grey area)

The **dropzone.directive.ts** has a function isEventInside I tried tweaking it but was not able to resolve for Issue(2).

The chain of events how the drag drop works is , in hello.component we have output events dragStart and drop which are present in **draggable.directive.ts** and **dropzone.directive.ts**.

Stackblitz link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1gjtab?file=src/app/hello.component.html

draggable.directive

```
import { Directive, EventEmitter, HostBinding, HostListener, Output, 
       ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
     selector: '[appDraggable],[appDroppable]'
 })
export class DraggableDirective {
@HostBinding('class.draggable') draggable = true;

 pointerId?: number;

@HostBinding('attr.touch-action') touchAction = 'none';

@Output() dragStart = new EventEmitter<PointerEvent>();
@Output() dragMove = new EventEmitter<PointerEvent>();
@Output() dragEnd = new EventEmitter<PointerEvent>();

@HostBinding('class.dragging') dragging = false;

constructor(public element: ElementRef) {}

@HostListener('pointerdown', ['$event'])
 onPointerDown(event: PointerEvent): void {
  if (event.button !== 0) {
  return;
 }

  this.pointerId = event.pointerId;
  this.dragging = true;
  this.dragStart.emit(event);
 }

 @HostListener('document:pointermove', ['$event'])
  onPointerMove(event: PointerEvent): void {
   if (!this.dragging || event.pointerId !== this.pointerId) {
    return;
 }
   this.dragMove.emit(event);
 }

 @HostListener('document:pointercancel', ['$event'])
 @HostListener('document:pointerup', ['$event'])
   onPointerUp(event: PointerEvent): void {
   if (!this.dragging || event.pointerId !== this.pointerId) {
    return;
 }
  this.dragging = false;
  this.dragEnd.emit(event);
 }
}
```

dropzone.directive

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, HostBinding, HostListener, 
 OnInit, Output, SkipSelf } from '@angular/core';
import { DroppableService } from './droppable.service';

@Directive({
 selector: '[appDropzone]',
 providers: [DroppableService]
})

export class DropzoneDirective implements OnInit {

 @HostBinding('class.dropzone-activated') activated = false;
 @HostBinding('class.dropzone-entered') entered = false;

 @Output() drop = new EventEmitter<PointerEvent>();
 @Output() remove = new EventEmitter<PointerEvent>();

 private clientRect: ClientRect;

 constructor(@SkipSelf() private allDroppableService: DroppableService,
          private innerDroppableService: DroppableService,
          private element: ElementRef) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
   this.allDroppableService.dragStart$.subscribe(() => this.onDragStart());
   this.allDroppableService.dragEnd$.subscribe(event => 
      this.onDragEnd(event));

   this.allDroppableService.dragMove$.subscribe(event => {
    if (this.isEventInside(event)) {
    this.onPointerEnter();
    } else {
    this.onPointerLeave();
    }
    });

   this.innerDroppableService.dragStart$.subscribe(() => 
    this.onInnerDragStart());
   this.innerDroppableService.dragEnd$.subscribe(event => 
   this.onInnerDragEnd(event));
}

private onPointerEnter(): void {
    if (!this.activated) {
     return;
   }

    this.entered = true;
   }

private onPointerLeave(): void {
    if (!this.activated) {
     return;
   }
    this.entered = false;
   }

private onDragStart(): void {
      this.clientRect = this.element.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
      this.activated = true;
   }

private onDragEnd(event: PointerEvent): void {
    if (!this.activated) {
    return;
   }
   if (this.entered) {
    this.drop.emit(event);
   }

    this.activated = false;
    this.entered = false;
   }

 private onInnerDragStart() {
     this.activated = true;
     this.entered = true;
 }

 private onInnerDragEnd(event: PointerEvent) {
     if (!this.entered) {
       this.remove.emit(event);
     }
    this.activated = false;
    this.entered = false;
 }

 private isEventInside(event: PointerEvent) {
   return event.clientX >= this.clientRect.left &&
          event.clientX <= this.clientRect.right &&
          event.clientY >= this.clientRect.top &&
          event.clientY <= this.clientRect.bottom;
 }
 }
```

hello.component

```
<div #parentparent id="toget" class="dropzone"
   [ngStyle]="{'width':'400px', 'border':'1px solid black', 'height':'340px'                   
   'margin-top':'120px'}" appMovableArea appDropzone 
   (drop)="move(currentBox, dropzone1)">

<div class="box" appMovable
    *ngFor="let existingZone of existingDroppedItemZoneIn"
    (dragStart)="currentBox = existingZone" 
    (dragEnd)="onDragEnd($event,box)" #childchild>
    {{ existingZone.main }}
</div>

<div class="box" *ngFor="let box of dropzone1" appDroppable 
  (dragStart)="currentBox = box" appMovable 
  (dragEnd)="onDragEnd($event,box)" #childchild>
    {{ box.dis.dis }}
</div>    
</div>
```

app.component

```
<div *ngFor="let room of rooms"
      class="box"
      appDroppable
      (dragStart)="currentBox = room">
 {{ room.dis }}
 <div class="box box-helper" *appDraggableHelper>{{ room.dis }}</div>
</div>

<hello  [roomsFloorZone]='zonesToBePassed' 
        [currentBoxFloorZone]='currentBox'
        [existingDroppedItem] = 'droppedItem' 
        (floorToParent)="updateFloorRooms($event)"
        [ngStyle]="{'margin- top':'90px'}">
</hello>
```

droppable.directive

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { DroppableService } from './droppable.service';

@Directive({
 selector: '[appDroppable]'
})
export class DroppableDirective {

 constructor(private droppableService: DroppableService) { }

@HostListener('dragStart', ['$event'])
 onDragStart(event: PointerEvent): void {
 this.droppableService.onDragStart(event);
}

@HostListener('dragMove', ['$event'])
 onDragMove(event: PointerEvent): void {
 this.droppableService.onDragMove(event);
}

@HostListener('dragEnd', ['$event'])
 onDragEnd(event: PointerEvent): void {
 this.droppableService.onDragEnd(event);
}

}
```

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen No please refer to the second stackblitz link

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen and also the issue is not google chrome as I am running both the links on Chrome and my project as well on chrome

Comment: It doesn't seem to fix all of your problems, but if you "provide" GlobalPositionStrategy in your "draggable" module, and then inject it into the constructor of draggable-helper.directive.ts rather than trying to create a new instance there, it fixes the compiler error, and seems to work a bit better.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek ,  Will this fix issue 1

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek , sorry I was not able to make it working , like I have a shared module, I imported and exported overlay, overlayref, globalpositioningstrategy in shared module now in my draggable-helper.directive , when I mention Overlay in constructor it says cannot find name 'Overlay'

Comment: Also in both the stackblitz link there is version difference in the dependencies as well

Comment: @Enthu as requested, I took a look at this question, but not sure if I will be able to help you with that. Anyway, suggest you to use angular cdk implementation, which shall help you to easier implement the desired functionality.

Comment: @GCSDC , yeah in my stackblitz I have used cdk ,but getting error as mentioned in issue 1 , and it would be great if you could help me in resolving the issue 2 , thanks , there is version difference between the dependencies in the 2 stackblitz link I have given , so If u could help me

Comment: @GCSDC , And drag and drop is already working , only the issue is the drop part , as requested by me how can I drop anywhere instead of the box getting dropped at only one top,left position

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm correct. Since the discussion is quite long I start a different answer...

The two different Stackblitz versions for DnD use as well different versions from Angular. The one with one argument is using Angular 5.2.4 and the not working is using 8.1.4.

I would guess that the initialization should be something like

```
  private positionStrategy = new GlobalPositionStrategy();
...
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.positionStrategy.attach(...);
```

for correct usage please refer [to](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/api#GlobalPositionStrategy)

The other issue I see is that the DnD-image is not set properly. You need to set it cuz the drop is already where the mouse cursor is pointing to.

Comment: thanks for the answer, The first issue pointed out by you I'll try it out, for the 2nd issue , the thing is I can drag and drop the box but every time I drag and drop it goes and sits in same top,left position in the grey area whereas ideally, what my objective is how can I make the box drop anywhere within the grey area, it would be great if you could help (Note: Once after the box is dropped then it can be dragged and moved within the grey area that works fine)

Comment: About the dropping I don't really understand. There is `(dragover)` listener on which you could observere the emitted events. You could therein quite easily check additional details (e.g. current box, `event.offsetY`, whatever JS provides ;-)). One challenge was to use `event.preventDefault()` from further populating... Hope this makes sense.

Comment: could you please modify the second stackblitz link in case you get a chance , it would be of great help , thanks